# Adding a cgi-bin directory to OpenShift?

Tags: .htaccess, openshift, cgi-bin

I am trying to add a cgi-bin directory to an OpenShift project, it should be simple, but I think I am missing something.

I have created a cgi-bin directory under my /data/ directory, and did a chmod 755 on it.  I moved a "hello_world.pl" file to the directory and did a chmod 755 on it.  I then added a .htaccess file to that directory with these contents:

```
AddHandler perl-script .pl 
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
Options +ExecCGI
```

I then created a link to a "cgi-bin" directory in my /repo/ directory to this new cgi-bin directory with 755 permissions.  Lastly, I added another .htaccess file with these contents to the repo directory:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ var/lib/openshift/54fcd2cde...000015a/app-root/data/cgi-bin/
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl

<Directory var/lib/openshift/54fcd2cde...000015a/app-root/data/cgi-bin>
    SetHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
    Options +ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
```

I then restarted this application under OpenShift.

The first thing I am trying to do is see if I can get this hello_world.pl to execute from a browser - it won't - I get an Internal Server Error.  But I can do a "perl hello_world.pl" from the command line with no problems.

Anybody have any ideas what I am missing?  Thanks all.

Comment: What errors do you see in your log files about the internal server error?

Comment: Thanks moleculartear; the logs said that the ScriptAlias entry in .htaccess was suspicious.  I deleted it and the code now works.  Thanks for your input.